# Django: Class has no 'objects' member

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, backend

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

def meldungen(request):
context = {
    'posts': Post.objects.all()
}
return render(request, 'web/meldungen.html', context)
```

Top: There is the Error in line 4: *Class 'Post' has no 'objects' member - pylint(no-member). I tried to migrate it an the problem wasn't solved. But in the Django docs I read:

> If you don’t add your own Manager, Django will add an attribute objects containing default Manager instance.

( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/class/ )

I read all Stack Overflow Posts for this problem but no solution worked. I (I use VSC) tried installing pylint-django, reinstalled pylint and pip .... But here it looks like there isn't just an linter warning, because on the server (Debug is true) appears this error:

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\(...)\web\templates\web\base.html, error at line 9

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not'NoneType'
```

In this line:
[image]

If I comment the error line in the view.py file out the site works without any errors. Also I tried render the view with dummy-data as context which works. If I using the shell to take an look on my posts db there aren't problems:

#### Shell:

```
In [1]: from web.models import Post

In [2]: Post.objects.all()
Out[3]: <QuerySet [<Post: Title 1>, <Post: Title 2>]>
```

> FIXED: The problem was a bug at another place in my code. This was just an pylint-error.

Comment: `Class 'Post' has no 'objects' member - pylint(no-member)` That's a pylint error, not an actual python error.  In this case I think you can ignore it.

Comment: The Problem is that the view /meldungen isn't working with the error i tell over the shell script.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct template?  Line 9 doesn't appear to have any `int()` calls.

Comment: Yes, thats head tag inside my base template and i know this, thats my problem because i don't understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: The screenshot of the code is from the /meldungen with debug on.

Comment: Can you show us the `web/meldungen.html` template?

Comment: Sure, i've added the meldungen.html.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! In my template was the error (post.id)

Comment: How did the error in the template cause the linter error? I'm facing the same problems. My code works but I have linter errors all over and its annoying. I followed the below post on the git and switched to Pylance but the errors are still present. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14648